# Java input method for Virtual Keyboard

Tags: java, awtrobot, virtual-keyboard

I am facing a problem in implementing Input method for Virtual Keyboard. Currently I am using robot class for sending input to any application from virtual keyboard. But for that I need to create mapping of key-code and unicode, which is not consistent on different keyboard layout, can I directly pass the UNICODE to any application using Input method without worry about mapping between keycode and unicode.

Any useful link or sample code will be useful.

It is a simple Java program which is always on top of any application and work as onscreen keyboard. Using a mouse while you press any button (key) of the keyboard, the corresponding character will be typed in the application running below. This is working perfectly for English Alphabets. I am facing problem while I am doing for unicode.

---

find the code snippet below

```
   public static void simulateKeyEvent(char key){
    try{
            AWTKeyStroke awtKS = AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStroke(key);
            int key_code = awtKS.getKeyCode();
            System.out.println("key = "+key+" keyCode = "+key_code);
            robot.keyPress(key_code);
            robot.keyRelease(key_code);

    }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How I sovled it:

```
//on startup: override the SystemEventQueue
EventQueue eventQueue = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue();
final OwnEventQueue newEventQueue = new OwnEventQueue();
eventQueue.push(newEventQueue);
//because dispatchEvent is protected
public class OwnEventQueue {
    private final static OwnEventQueue instance;

    static{
        instance = new OwnEventQueue();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatchEvent(AWTEvent event) {
        super.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    public static OwnEventQueue getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
//then onpress of keyboard button
Character character = getCharacter();
int[] events = {KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED};
for (int i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    KeyEvent pressKeyEvent = new KeyEvent(focusComponent, events[i], System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, 0, character.charValue());
    OwnEventQueue.getInstance().dispatchEvent(pressKeyEvent);
}
robotKeystrokeSender.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
robotKeystrokeSender.delay(10);
robotKeystrokeSender.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your virtual keyboard used as a device by your OS ?
Or, in other words, have you tried considering it as a "real" keyboard ?
According to Java hardware abstraction, were your virtual keyboard to be considered as a driver, it should simply work like a real keyboard.

**EDIT** : according to comment, this is not a virtual device, but a Java application, as a consequence, probleme is different.

According to Javadoc, Robot can send [key strokes given as int](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress(int)). To create those key strokes from characters, I would recommand you create them using `getKeystroke(char)` before to transform them into integer values using `getKeycode()`. This way, you would have integer values associatesd your unicode characters, whichever they are.

**EDIT 2** : once again, a modification ;-)

it seems like `getKeyStroke(String)` "should" handle unicode characters.

Comment: No it is not a device for OS. It is simple Java program which is always on top of any application and work as onscreen keyboard. using a mouse while you press any button (key) of the keyboard, the corresponding character will be typed in the application running below. This is working perfectly for English Alphabets. I am facing problem while using I am doing for unicode.

Comment: I tried what you have suggested but It is not working for UNICODE character. It is always returning "0" as keycode for all the UNICODE character

Comment: Interesting, can you put an example of the code you use to generate KeyStroke then key code ?

Comment: Thank you! but is not working for Devangri unicode characters I don't know why?

Comment: Well, this time I must confess i'm a bit moved away from my base skills. However, do you display these characters on screen ? If so does it works correctly ?
And can you print the keycode used by the awt.robot ? maybe these characters are in the upper range of the unicode table, and as a consequence may be translated as negated integer (resulting in no stroke). But beware : what I say is only a shot in the dark.

Comment: Once again thank you  Riduide! your input is very useful for me.. I am keep trying.. :)

Comment: I am able to display the characters on top of the Jbutton and able to display on other application using awt.robot (when I know the KEY_CODE of the UNICODE character). The problem is I am not able to generate the KEY_CODE from the UNICODE charater